# Flutter - Put tapped card in front of stack cards

Tags: flutter, dart, animation, stack

When I tap on a specific card I want that card will put in front of other cards like in this photo ->
[image]

When I tap on an other card, it will be put in bottom but it is always behind other cards, like in these photos: (sorry for the scale)

[image]
[image]

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final mediaQuery = MediaQuery.of(context);
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('PICK A CARD'),
      ),
      body: SizedBox.expand(
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Stack(
            children: [
              AnimatedContainer(
                duration: kAnimationDuration,
                height: totalHeightTotalCard(),
                width: mediaQuery.size.width,
              ),
              for (int i = 0; i < creditCards.length; i++)
                AnimatedPositioned(
                  bottom: _getCardTopPosititoned(i, i == selectedCardIndex),
                  curve: Curves.easeInOutCubic,
                  duration: kAnimationDuration,
                  child: AnimatedScale(
                    scale: _getCardScale(i, i == selectedCardIndex),
                    duration: kAnimationDuration,
                    child: GestureDetector(
                        onTap: () {
                          setState(() {
                            selectedCardIndex = i;
                            creditCards;
                          });
                        },
                        child: creditCards[i],
                        ),
                  ),
                ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

how can I change the order of cards and put the tapped card in front of them?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps take your list, and removeAt the index point of your card selected, and then insert at the index 0.

creditCards.removeAt()
creditCards.insert()